# How to download file from dialog box in SlimerJS with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

I am using PhantomJS and SlimerJS to download a .xls file from a web.

I do not have a download URL.
The file is automatically generated.

I tried with CasperJS and I could not.

**How to download this file?**

[Example capture JPG from Dialog Box SlimerJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTIvI.jpg)

Comment: We recently discussed the issue and it seems that one cannot control file download dialog in SlimerJS. There's a possible workaround, if you can `page.open(file_url)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433334/handle-download-dialog-box-in-slimerjs/35434511#35434511

Comment: Thanks Vaviloff.
You know if it would be possible in another language or library ??
I just do crawler in JS